# Move folder structure across multiple directories

Tags: files, cp, mv, move

I am trying to move one a bunch of files at once, one directory up.

This is what I tried, but did not work:

> `mv ./*/__test__/index.js ./*/data.js`

```
.
├── alpha
│   ├── __test__
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── test.js
└── beta
    ├── __test__
    │   └── index.js
    ├── index.js
    └── test.js
```

To this:

```
.
├── alpha
│   ├── data.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── test.js
└── beta
    ├── data.js
    ├── index.js
    └── test.js
```

How can I do this in unix?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use wildcards in the target argument. So at least some scripting is required:

```
for d in *; do
    if [[ -d "$d" ]]; then
        pushd "$d"
        mv __test__/index.js ./data.js
        popd
    fi
done
```

Comment: Look more closely.  He wants to rename, not just move.

Comment: @Wildcard Yeah, figured that out in the meantime :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example that will move the files.

```
for f in $(find -name index.js | grep __test__ ); do echo $f; destination=$(echo $f | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $2}'); mv ${f} ./$destination/data.js; done
```

I have tested this, it does perform the move as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -path '*/__test__/*' -type f -name "index.js" \ 
    -execdir echo mv -vt ../data.js {} \;
```

Remove `echo` which is for dry-run to run `mv` command on files.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot about gnu `parallel`!

```
ls -d -- */ | parallel "cd {} && mv ./__test__/index.js ./data.js 2>/dev/null"
```

Comment: Or just: `parallel "cd {} && mv ./__test__/index.js ./data.js 2>/dev/null" ::: */`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `echo`s for the real changing.

```
for i in */__test__/index.js; do
    echo mv -v "$i" "${i%%/*}/data.js"
    echo rm -vr "${i%/*}"
done
```

**Before**

```
.
├── alpha
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── __test__
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── test.js
└── beta
    ├── index.js
    ├── __test__
    │   └── index.js
    └── test.js
```

**After**

```
.
├── alpha
│   ├── data.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── test.js
└── beta
    ├── data.js
    ├── index.js
    └── test.js
```